# How did Uber fingerprint iPhones to identify them even after the Uber app was deleted?

Tags: ios

In 2015 Uber was fingerprinting iPhones to reduce fraud in China.

What methods were they using to do this? Was it as simple as recording the serial number in a database? Were they using private methods?

From the [NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/23/technology/travis-kalanick-pushes-uber-and-himself-to-the-precipice.html): 
"To halt the activity, Uber engineers assigned a persistent identity to iPhones with a small piece of code, a practice called “fingerprinting.” Uber could then identify an iPhone and prevent itself from being fooled even after the device was erased of its contents.

There was one problem: Fingerprinting iPhones broke Apple’s rules. Mr. Cook believed that wiping an iPhone should ensure that no trace of the owner’s identity remained on the device.

So Mr. Kalanick told his engineers to “geofence” Apple’s headquarters in Cupertino, Calif., a way to digitally identify people reviewing Uber’s software in a specific location. Uber would then obfuscate its code for people within that geofenced area, essentially drawing a digital lasso around those it wanted to keep in the dark. Apple employees at its headquarters were unable to see Uber’s fingerprinting."

Comment: Don't do this. There is a good reason Apple doesn't want apps to track users. Respect your users, don't treat them badly. And what if I buy a used iOS device or give my old one to a family member? Why should your app keep on thinking the device belongs to the previous owner?

Comment: @rmaddy I don't want to do this at all. I want to know what Uber was doing, how they were doing it to know how bad it was. But you have great advice nonetheless. :)

Comment: I too am interested in this. [This TechCrunch article](https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/23/uber-responds-to-report-that-it-tracked-users-who-deleted-its-app/) refers to Will Strafach who claims that "They were dynamically loading IOKit.framework (a private framework), then dynamically loading some symbols from it to iterate through the device registry ... the only persistent identifier they actually use appears to be the device Serial Number." I would appreciate it if someone could write a more elaborate description (and also comment on whether this is still possible as this code was from 2014).

Answer (score 1):

Found more info and a potential method on [this article](http://daringfireball.net/2017/04/uber_identifying_and_tagging_iphones).

Will Strafach examined a 2014 build of the Uber iOS app and found them using private APIs to use IOKit to pull the device serial number from the device registry.

https://twitter.com/chronic/status/856250223777206273

There might be more, but this alone is a blatant violation of App Store policy. [Strafach confirms](https://twitter.com/chronic/status/856333895050178560) that the technique Uber was using no longer works in iOS 10.]

Github project here - https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/7adc1d13946fca6fcb4b5f0b6e45911ab4a9a671/UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m

Answer (score 0):

Even I was too curious to know. I read a tweet, that basically hints that they exploited IOKits registries to do this.

Seems like they got some identifier from IOKits internals and saved it at their end to identify as device.

https://twitter.com/chronic/status/856250223777206273